# Display image from create model blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model and when I am creating a new one I want to be able to store an image from controller, like this:

```
public function create($id)
{
    //
    $user = User::FindOrFail($id);
    $photos = Photo::all();
    return view('posts.create', ['user'=>$user, 'photos'=>$photos]);
}

public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'text' => 'nullable|max:255',
        'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'user_id' => 'nullable|int',
    ]);
    // return 'passed validation';
    $size = $request->file('image')->getSize();
    $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

    $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images/', $name);
    $photo = new Photo();
    $photo->name = $name;
    $photo->size = $size;
    $photo->save();

    $a = new Post;
    $a->title = $validateData['title'];
    $a->text = $validateData['text'];
    $a->image = $photo;
    $a->user_id = $id;
    $a->save();

    session()->flash('message', 'Post was created');
    return redirect()->route('posts.index', ['id'=>$id]);
}
```

While I try to also display all available images in create blade:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.store', ['id'=>$user->id])}}">
@csrf
<p>Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}"></p>
<p>Text: <input type="text" name="text" value="{{old('text')}}"></p>
@csrf
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="Upload">
<ul>
    @foreach ($photos as $photo)
    <li>
        <p>
            {{ $photo->name }}
        </p>
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/images/'. $photo->name) }}">
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<a href="{{route('posts.index', ['id'=>$user->id])}}">Cancel</a>
```

When I try to submit I get the following errors:

> The image must be an image.
> The image must be a file of type: jpg, png, jpeg, gif, svg.

This error can't be true as I try to upload only jpg and png images, but I can't understand where I do something wrong.

Edit: Is there a way to store the image without declaring a new model?

Comment: There are two forms nested in each other, please remove inner form tag and you'll be fine

Comment: I've removed the second form, but I get the same error

Comment: plz update the code in question also, so we can check

Comment: You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` element for `<input type="file">` inputs to work properly in Laravel.